# Polars aggregation warning using when->then

Tags: python-polars

Consider the following:

```
In [9]: df
Out[9]: 
shape: (2, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 1   │
│ 2   ┆ 1   │
└─────┴─────┘

In [10]: df.groupby("a").agg(pl.when(pl.col("b") == 1).then(pl.col("b")))
The predicate '[(col("b")) == (1)]' in 'when->then->otherwise' is not a valid aggregation and might produce a different number of rows than the groupby operation would. This behavior is experimental and may be subject to change
Out[10]: 
shape: (2, 2)
┌─────┬───────────┐
│ a   ┆ b         │
│ --- ┆ ---       │
│ i64 ┆ list[i64] │
╞═════╪═══════════╡
│ 2   ┆ [1]       │
│ 1   ┆ [1]       │
└─────┴───────────┘
```

Is there something to worry about? The when->then has to produce a value even if it's null.

Comment: The warning seems to be telling you that it's not sure if it's a problem. Why not put your `when` `then` in a `with_columns` before the `groupby`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in the aggregation arises from comparing the group `"B"` with a literal `1` and replacing with the group `"B"`. We haven't formalized the vectorization rules for that expression yet, hence the warning.

It is more explicit and (easier for use to understand), to apply your ternary expression in a `with_columns` and then do an aggregation:

```py
df = pl.from_repr("""shape: (2, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 1   │
│ 2   ┆ 1   │
└─────┴─────┘
""")

(df.with_columns(
    pl.when(pl.col("b") == 1).then(pl.col("b"))
).groupby("a").all())
```

```
shape: (2, 2)
┌─────┬───────────┐
│ a   ┆ b         │
│ --- ┆ ---       │
│ i64 ┆ list[i64] │
╞═════╪═══════════╡
│ 1   ┆ [1]       │
│ 2   ┆ [1]       │
└─────┴───────────┘
```